# ' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: -notcontain' in Get-ADUser Filter cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Unable to get the AD users created in the past 1 year which is not contains the specific Domain name pattern:

```
$laterThan = (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)
$filter = { (whenCreated -gt $laterThan) -and (userPrincipalName -notcontain $((Get-ADDomain).Name)) }
$properties = 'canonicalName', 'whenCreated', 'displayName', 'lastlogondate'

Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties
```

Error showing as:

> Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: ' (whenCreated -gt $laterThan) -and
> (userPrincipalName -notcontain $((Get-ADDomain).Name)) ' Error
> Message: 'Operator Not supported: -notcontain' at position: '55'. At
> line:5 char:1
>
> - Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
>   ```

However, the IDE not showing any issue:
[image]

Comment: Isnt the operator -notcontains? I think you're missing an s

Comment: Maybe my guess is wrong, but the ActiveDirectory Filter doesn't seem to support `contains` or `notcontains` the possible FilterOperator are `"-eq" | "-le" | "-ge" | "-ne" | "-lt" | "-gt"| "-approx" | "-bor" | "-band" | "-recursivematch" | "-like" | "-notlike"`. Ref.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps

Comment: Yes, that does make sense @Paxz, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Isaac no problem, hopefully, you also learn as well on this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean `-notcontains` but that operator is not supported for that cmdlet. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps#parameters).

Also, that operator works with collections, not strings. If you want to check if a string contains another string, use the `-like` operator and wildcards:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like '*$((Get-ADDomain).Name)*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the correct operator is `-notcontains`

Check them all [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7).